# Users with different permission getting different Get-ADUser Output

Tags: powershell, active-directory, get-aduser

I am a bit lost here and don't know what to search for to make some progress. So maybe someone can help me out.

I am working in an already existing Active Directory, with already existing users, computers, GPOs and all those stuff you need for a working infrastructure. And I am not sure if my problem lies somewhere in here.

Now I want to run the following PowerShell script to get some user accounts but:

```
(Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "((memberOf=CN=All,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=de))").Count
```

As a user that is only admin on some servers e.g. the fileserver and with no other privileges, the script shows only 600 accounts.
If I run the exact same script as the domain admin, I get the correct amount of 11000 accounts.

The results are the same no matter on which server I run the script - even on a DC itself.

I tried to set the resultsize to $null but this doesn't change anything.
The non-privileged user gets the wrong number of accounts, every time, and every time the same wrong number.

So my questions are:
Does anybody know why?
Does anybody know how to change that?
Which permissions does my account need to get the right number but without having domain admin permissions?

And even if you just know some keywords for me to search for, I would be happy...

Comment: Does the group `CN=All,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=de` have members from other Domains ? Are there nested groups in it ?

Comment: Try to find an account that is missing from the list.  Do you have permissions to the OU where the actual account exists.  That LDAPFilter will basically try and traverse every account you have access to and check if the memberOf includes that group.   IF the account you use to run the command doesn't have rights to particular containers, then its not going to check these.  Personally, I would use Get-ADGroupMember instead, and then pipe that into Get-ADUser.  If you don't have permissions to the accounts, then this will be obvious as you will get a lot of errors on the Get-ADUser part.

Comment: You are using Windows Credentials.  Windows Credentials you must have access to the all the machines you are trying to get data.  Windows uses Group Policies.  So you have to contact a Admin for Group Policies to get the correct permission to access all the machines.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon No members from other domains. No nested groups.

Comment: @mikee which permissions do i need exactly?

In the meantime i tried to add the permissions to read all user properties in the whole AD, but that didn't changed the result... 

And yes. I get a result (with Get-ADUser -Identity "name") for an user. This user is in the group. And this user is not part of the result of the 600 accounts...

So what do i miss?

Comment: @mikee god damn it! While writing my last reply it hasn't worked. The same code just two minutes later, worked fine.

So what was it? A replication delay? I tried on the DC where i did the permission changes... so i don't know, but it works now.

So you were right, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

So, as mentioned in the question and @mikee already told in the comments the problem lies in inapropriate permissions.

While i tried out some different permissions i could pin it down to the permissions to read all attributes for group objects. I am pretty sure, that you don't need to read all of them, but in our old and messy AD it is a pain to figure out which aren't necessary.

As original solved [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/167371/what-permissions-are-required-for-enumerating-users-groups-in-active-directory) you have to right click on your domain (or on the OU, where the permissions should take place) and choose "Properties". In the "Security"-tab you open the advanced window and add a new entry.

There you have to choose first which user or group gets this permission.
Then you need to aply it to group objects. Scroll a bit down and check the box for the permission to read all attributes (or if you better know which are required, choose only them individually).

It may take some time before the changes are working - even on the DC where you made the changes.